# how to get center_changed latitude and longitude in angular google map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using angular google map https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/ . When user dragend the map. I need to get his center latitude and longitude like ola or uber app.

I got a demo in this link, but this demo displays lat and lng while drag  http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_21.html

I don't know how to execute this. Below is my code. Please help me. Any help should be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
$scope.map = {
              center: {
                latitude: $scope.set_latitude, //current location
                longitude: $scope.set_longitude
              },
              control: {}, 
              zoom: 12, 
              bounds: {},
              events:
                  { 
                    dragend: function (mapModel, eventName, marker, orignalEventArgs) {
                        alert('dragend');
                    }, 
                    tilesloaded: function(map, eventName, originalEventArgs){

                    var e = originalEventArgs[0]; 
                        var ret = {
                            id: 0,
                            latitude: $scope.set_latitude, // marker current location
                            longitude: $scope.set_longitude, 
                            title: 'Your Location',
                            icon:'image/marker.png'
                          };  

                          $scope.randomMarkers.push(ret); 
                    }

                  } ,

                  markersEvents: {
                    click: function(marker, eventName, model) { 
                        $scope.map.window.model = model;
                        $scope.map.window.show = true;
                    }
                  },    
                  window: {
                    marker: {},
                    show: false,
                    closeClick: function() {
                      this.show = false;
                    },
                    options: {}
                  }
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer myself after a long workout given on google map events.

To get dragend lat and lng details change this code

```
dragend: function (mapModel, eventName, marker, orignalEventArgs) {
   alert('dragend');
}
```

to

```
dragend: function (map, eventName) {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    $scope.latitude_n = center.lat();
    $scope.longitude_n = center.lng(); console.log($scope.latitude_n+','+$scope.longitude_n); // center location details
},
```

If you want center_changed event lat and lng details add this code

```
center_changed:function (map, eventName){
    var center = map.getCenter();
    $scope.latitude_n = center.lat();
    $scope.longitude_n = center.lng(); console.log($scope.latitude_n+','+$scope.longitude_n); // center location details
},
```

Good luck. Cheers.